# How does QML focus propagate?

Tags: qt, focus, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

I am trying to figure out how to properly set focus in my application.

I have a component MyItem.qml, which I want to change its background when any of its children gets focus. I also have a MyDerivedItem.qml that derives from MyItem.qml that also should change the background of the base class if any of its children gets focus.

If I understood the documentation correctly, if a component gets focus the focus property of all its parents in the hierarchy are set to true (or until a FocusScope component is reached).

If this is true, then when I press any of the TextFields in MyItem.qml or MyDerivedItem.qml the myItem.focus property should change to true and the background change its color.

I have tried to make a small example of what I want to do, but it does not behave as I expect.

```
//main.qml
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

ApplicationWindow {
    height: 768
    width: 1024
    visible: true

    MyDerivedItem {
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        width: parent.width / 2
    }
    MyDerivedItem {
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        width: parent.width / 2
    }
}

//MyItem.qml
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

Rectangle {
    id: myItem

    default property alias data: column.data

    color: focus ? "red" : "green"

    Column {
        id: column

        TextField {
            placeholderText: "Input Text Here"
        }
    }
}

//MyDerivedItem.qml
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

MyItem {
    id: myDerivedItem

    TextField {
        placeholderText: "Derived Input Text Here"
    }

    TextField {
        placeholderText: "Derived Input Text Here"
    }

    TextField {
        placeholderText: "Derived Input Text Here"
    }

    TextField {
        placeholderText: "Derived Input Text Here"
    }

    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to my problem was a minor change. Adding `FocusScope` to `MyItem.qml` as follows:

```
//MyItem.qml
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

FocusScope {
    id: focusScope

    default property alias data: column.data

    Rectangle {
        id: myItem

        anchors.fill: parent
        color: focusScope.focus ? "red" : "green"

        Column {
            id: column
            anchors.fill: parent

            TextField {
                placeholderText: "Input Text Here"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is somewhat doumented [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-input-focus.html). Accoding to that the propagation is: Qt -> QQuickWindow -> Item-with-focus.
There is no traversal of the object tree, but the focusing rather happens directly.

There is one exception to this rule, that is the `FocusScope` which acts as the focused `Item` towards the scene or a `FocusScope` in a higher hirarchy.
So basically you can say, in addition to the object-tree, there is a second *focus-tree* where each node is a `FocusScope` and all other `Items` are leaves.
Each `FocusScope`-Node might have one child that has focus.
Children of an `Item` in the object-tree might be siblings to their object-parents in the focus-tree.